# What is wrong with my pagination in my react app? (with semantic ui)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pagination, semantic-ui

So I am making a react app with semantic ui, that communicates with my own backend and displays news. I want to use pagination, that I tried to make it like it is said in this article: https://www.codementor.io/@maseh87/paginating-a-react-app-with-semantic-ui-x1g4a0t79

So here is my app.tsx:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import MainPage from "./pages/MainPage";
import NewsDetailPage from "./pages/NewsDetailPage";

interface AppProps {}

interface AppState {}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <Navbar />
        </header>
        <div className="ui container" style={{paddingBottom: "2rem"}}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/news/:id" element={<NewsDetailPage />} />
            <Route path="/news" element={<MainPage />} />

            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/news" replace />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my main page, this includes the pagination:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import NewsList from "../components/news list/NewList";
import { NewsModel } from "../models/news.model";
import { newsService } from "../services/news.service";
import MainNews from "../components/main news/MainNews";
import { Pagination } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const MainPage = () => {
  const [news, setNews] = useState<NewsModel[]>([]);
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(1);
  const [apiUrl, setApiUrl] = useState('http://localhost:3001/api/');


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNews = async () => {
      setNews(await newsService.getNews());
    };

    fetchNews();
  }, []);

  const [main, ...rest] = news;

  const onChange = (pageInfo: any) => {
    setActivePage(pageInfo.activePage);
    setApiUrl('http://localhost:3001/api/?page=' + activePage.toString());
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <MainNews main={main} />
      <NewsList news={rest} />
      <Pagination 
      activePage={activePage}
      onPageChange={onChange}
      totalPages={10}
      ellipsisItem={null}
    />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainPage;
```

So I want to display the first piece of news with a different style and then the list of remaining news. But I also want this on only the first page, on the rest I just want to see the list.
But what is wrong with the pagination things? It displays the numbers of the pages, but nothing happens when I click on the next page.

Comment: Is the issue in this line  ? `setApiUrl('http://localhost:3001/api/?page=' + activePage.toString());` change it to  `setApiUrl('http://localhost:3001/api/?page=' + pageInfo.activePage.toString());` .. a guess .... otherwise it would be easy if you can create a reproducible sample and add link, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz

Comment: Still doesn't  work unfortunately :(

Comment: please consider creating a reproducible sample and attach the link, or add errors if any *